# Is there any way I can apply different inline style when I mapping through array of objects inside jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The reason why I wanna do this because I want to apply different animation-delay for each item.

I use simple exmaple here.

I want to be able to display news1 as red, news1 as blue, and news1 as green.
Is there any way I can achieve that?

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const InfoTitle = styled.div({
});

const Red = {color: 'red'}
const blue = {color: 'blue'}
const green = {color: 'green'}



const  App = () => {
  const array = [
    {
      title: 'news1',
      content: 'brabrabrabra1'
    },
    {
      title: 'news2',
      content: 'brabrabrabra2'
    },
    {
      title: 'news3',
      content: 'brabrabrabra3'
    }
  ]
  return (
      <>
      {array.map((item, i) => (<InfoTitle key={i}>{item.title}</InfoTitle>))}
      </>
  )

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another property of color inside your objects

```
const  App = () => {
  const array = [
    {
      title: 'news1',
      content: 'brabrabrabra1',
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      title: 'news2',
      content: 'brabrabrabra2',
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      title: 'news3',
      content: 'brabrabrabra3'
      color: 'green'
    }
  ]
  return (
      <>
      {array.map((item, i) => (<InfoTitle style={{backgroundColor: item.color}} key={i}>{item.title}</InfoTitle>))}
      </>
  )

}
```

Comment: If I'm not able to change the data of array, (let's say I can only do fetch), is there any way I can pull this off?

Comment: @KensukeShibata Can you have array of colors in order?

Comment: As long as it’s local, I think I can. 

Data of array changes day by day. 
Data has title and content.
I might add new news or delete it from Contentful. 
The number of arrays could be 3 or even more. 
But I wan to apply this inline style for each mapping jsx

item1: animationDelay: 0s
item2: animationDelay: 3s
item3: animationDelay: 6s
item4: animationDelay: 9s
......